# Socket IO detect if user leaves a room

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I want to listen for the event in which a user leaves a room. From what I've researched, `socket.rooms` apparently contains the rooms that a socket is in. However, when I listen for the `disconnect` event from a socket, apparently the socket left the room prior to disconnect. Therefore, `socket.rooms` will yield an empty object after the disconnect event. I need to listen specifically for the event in which a user leaves a room, not the socket disconnect event, since I have an array of room objects and wish to delete the user from the room when they leave.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A user cannot leave a room without your server removing them from the room or when the user disconnects.  Clients cannot leave a room on their own.  So, to know when a user leaves a room, you just need to hook into your own code that removes them from a room and also listen for the `disconnect` event.

Other than a disconnect, the only other way a user can leave a room is if your own code removes them from a room so you can just hook into that specific function and trigger the update of your own data structures when your own code removes them from the chat room.

For the `disconnect` event, if you are maintaining your own room data structures, then you can just remove a given socket from any room that you find it in when you get the `disconnect` event (e.g. search each room and remove it from any room that you find that socket in).

Comment: I am on this exact same problem,  and attempt to wrap SocketIO with data structures that make sense (for my problem domain).